# What is a good Spanish equivalent for "sledgehammer argument"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, modismos

So far I could not find any reasonable translation for "sledgehammer argument". Automatic translations spit out "argumento de mazo." However, everything indicates to me this is just one of those totally non-idiomatic automatic translations that make no sense.

Alternative English expressions from Wikipedia are: "thought-terminating cliché" (also known as a semantic stop-sign, a thought-stopper, bumper sticker logic, or cliché thinking)"

Answer (score 13):

[image: Sledge-hammer]

To my ear

> ### a sledge-hammer argument

is best translated as

> ### un argumento **demoledor**

Since the verb [**demoler**](https://dle.rae.es/devastar) means `to demolish, to knock-down`

> Del lat. demolīri.
> Conjug. c. mover.
>
> 1. tr. Deshacer, derribar, arruinar.

We are talking about something that "beats" a discussion in a way in which "eliminates all opposition". Note that [sledge-hammers "are most useful for demolishing work"](https://gearknows.com/sledge-hammer-used-for/)

> *(..) they are perfect to use for demolition work, driving large things like stakes into the ground and for breaking through hard materials*

I initially also thought of the word [**contundente**](https://dle.rae.es/contundente) (see lat [*contundere*](https://latin.cactus2000.de/showverb.en.php?verb=contundere) `to crush, to  beat, to pound to pieces`) since in that word Spanish  also holds a direct meaning associated with arguments.

To add more *punch* the expression could optionally carry the adjective "*devastador**, or the adverb "*devastadoramente*" since [**devastar**](https://dle.rae.es/devastar) means `to destroy, reduce something into pieces or ashes`)

Comment: That cursor on the image really confused me for a moment.

Comment: haha, I fixed that, thanks!

Comment: I thought "frase matona" (killer phrase) or "argumento matón" (killer argument)

Answer (score 6):

You can use *argumento [irrebatible](https://dle.rae.es/irrebatible)*:

> 1. adj. Que no se puede rebatir o refutar.

or *argumento [irrefutable](https://dle.rae.es/irrefutable)*:

> 1. adj. Que no se puede refutar.

where [refutar](https://dle.rae.es/refutar) means

> 1. tr. Contradecir o impugnar con argumentos o razones lo que otros dicen.

Comparing these suggestions to the ones in RubioRic's [answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/37466/24236), Google has 166000 results for ["argumento decisivo"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22argumento%20decisivo%22), 36400 results for ["argumento irrefutable"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22argumento%20irrefutable%22), 13400 results for ["argumento irrebatible"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22argumento%20irrebatible%22), and 793 results for ["argumento terminante"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22argumento%20terminante%22).

Comment: +1 for the other options and the comparison :-)

Comment: @RubioRic you win this time ;) but I do say "argumento irrefutable" more often, that is why I added the option.

Comment: Both are correct, but I would say that "argumento irrefutable" is more common. That doesn't mean that "argumento irrebatible" is non-idiomatic, it's perfectly fine too.
Other proposals such us "contundente" or "de peso" (added by me) are also OK, but they mean something like "strong argument", not necessary "strong argument that eliminates all opposition".
"Terminante" or "decisivo" can also match, but they are less used refering to an argument.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the adjective - equivalent to sledge-hammer in this context - that you are looking for is **terminante**. You gave me the idea with "though-**terminating** cliché"

According to the [Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sledge-hammer+argument) a sledge-hammer argument is

> A strong argument that eliminates all opposition

According to the DLE

> **[terminante](https://dle.rae.es/terminante)**
> 2. adj. Categórico, concluyente, ***que hace imposible cualquier insistencia o discusión*** sobre la cosa de que se trata.

The highlighted text is *almost* a direct translation of the idiom definition provided by the Free Dictionary, it says that "terminante" means that something makes impossible to continue insisting or discussing.

Another option is **decisivo**

DLE

> [**decisivo**](https://dle.rae.es/decisivo)
> 1.adj. Que decide o resuelve.

Oxford Dictionary

> [**decisive**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/decisive)
> 2. Having or showing the ability to make decisions quickly and effectively.

Answer (score 1):

**un argumento contundente**

Contundente literally means "blunt" and conveys, somewhat, the same kind of image that sledgehammer does.  It's rarely used with argumento, but it can be used this way.